# Caesar cipher in Java

Tags: java, string, cryptography

I'm trying to implement the [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

But while doing so I am getting an unexpected output which I am unable to rectify.

Will someone help me please?

My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;

public class encryptology
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int t, move = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String s = "", st = br.readLine();
        int l = st.length();

        for(int x = 0; x < l; x++){
            char c = st.charAt(x);
            t = (int)c;
            if(move != 0){
                t = t + move;
                if(t > 90){
                    t = t - 26;        
                }
                if(t < 65){
                    t += 26;
                }
                c = (char)t;
                s = st + c;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I entered `move = 2` and `st = charles`
The output was: `charles[`

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable.  Thanks.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 3) Try describing a) What you expected to happen b) What actually happened, and for utility c) Why you expected (a) to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing wrong string. You are acctualy setting result with starting string `st` and add encrypted char. Change

```
s=st+c;
```

to

```
s=s+c;
```

Comment: I inputted 1,a and got h

Comment: @user2511145, the code you have written assumes that the input contains only upper case characters. Try 1,A.

Comment: I don't know what are you expecting as an output. Here is the code http://ideone.com/KnJ6h5 and it is getting string encrypted.

Comment: I flagged your comment by mistake I am soooo sorry :-(

Comment: No problem :-) Vote for the answer.

Comment: @user987339 he cannot, 14 is one point short for the upvote priviledge, I'll put him at 19, its the new year :)